# Optimized Solution for Power Pokemon Problem

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to solve the following Question:

> A Power Pokemon Couple is a pair of pokemons with a sum of their power levels equal to a power of two.
> You are given an array power, containing the power levels of many pokemons. You can pick any two to make a power couple.
> Print the number of such power pokemon couples you can form using the given array.
> Note: Pokemons with different indices are considered different even if they have the same power level. Since the answer can be huge, print it modulo 10^9 + 7

> **Contraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= power.length <= 10^5
> 0 <= power[i] <= 22
> ```

> **Sample Input:**
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 3 5 7 9
> ```
>
> **Sample Output:**
> `4`

> **Explanation:**
> The power pokemon couples formed are (1,3), (1,7), (3,5) and, (7,9).
> Their respective sums are 4, 8, 8, and 16, all of which are powers of 2.

My Brute force solution for the Question is:

```java
static int countPair(int[] input, int n) { 
        int mod = 1000000007;
        Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            freq.put(input[i], freq.getOrDefault(input[i], 0)+ 1); 

        int pairsCount = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) { 
            int power = (int)Math.pow(2, i); 
            for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) { 
                int key = power - input[j]; 
                if(freq.containsKey(key)){
                    pairsCount += freq.get(k);
                }
                pairsCount = pairsCount%mod;
            } 
        } 
        return pairsCount / 2; 
    }
```

My code fails in larger test cases and in case of duplicate numbers. For example in an array [4,4,4,4], the answer must be 6 but my code gives 8.

I want a optimized code for the problem that works fine in array with duplicate numbers too.

Comment: There are various ways to approach this. Like: first take your example input, and ask yourself why you would get to 6. Then ... take your algorithm, and run it yourself, using a pen and a piece of paper. Write down the relevant variables, and then go through the whole thing, "instruction by instruction". Yes, that is very tedious, but there is no better way to understand your code . Alternatively, add print statements to your code, so that *any* relevant operation gets printed. Again, tedious, but in the end: you have to enable yourself to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: And note: consider to use more telling names for your variable names. `arr` doesn't tell much to the reader. Okay, an array, but what is its purpose. Same for `m`. So, a map ... but what do the keys and values represent?!